# Java Script Open Links within Multiple Divs in New Window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having trouble getting some code working when using multiple `div` tags with different `ids`.

This code is in the head of an `html` document and working properly for a single `div` `id`:

```
<!-- Start External Links in New Window Requires div id article -->
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[     
window.onload = function () {  
        var links = document.getElementById('article').getElementsByTagName('a');  
        for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {  
            links[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');}
        }  
//]]>  
</script>
<!-- End of External Links -->
```

I need this to work for multiple `divs` tags with different `IDs` on the same `html` page but the `document.getElementById` will only allow a single `div ID`.

I tried repeating the above code multiple times for each `div` but it only works with the very last iteration.

Does anyone know how to make the code work with multiple `div` tags with different `ids`?

Comment: Take a look at using css classes instead.

Comment: Perhaps look into [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName).

Comment: What does your HTML look like? I cannot reproduce this issue: http://jsfiddle.net/Y5ZZ3/1/

Comment: @412 "I tried repeating the above code multiple times for each div". Seems to work": http://jsfiddle.net/Y5ZZ3/1/

Comment: I ended up gong with class name and it works perfectly now. You can see the individual div ids I was working with if you run a search in the code for class="external". Here is a sample html page: http://www.engaygedweddings.com/ca/reception-halls/julia-morgan-ballroom.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace this part:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll("#article a");
```

with:

```
var links = document.getElementById('article').getElementsByTagName('a');
```

this will result all the a tags in the node with 'article' id.

but if you have multiple article nodes, you better  set the 'article' in 'class' attribute instead of setting as 'id'. then simply change the code like this:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll(".article a");
```

and if the 'a' tags are in the first level of article nodes childnodes you can also do this:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll(".article>a");
```

Comment: Thank you - the second to last option you gave works perfectly

Comment: This saved me from manually applying target=blank to an almost 3,000 page website! If anyone in the future sees this post and would benefit from the solution - I used class="external" and Mehran's suggestion - here's a sample page using the new code: http://www.engaygedweddings.com/ca/caterers-ca-gay-wedding/colettes-events.html

Answer (score 1):

change

```
var links = document.getElementById('article').getElementsByTagName('a');
```

to

```
var links = document.getElementsByClassName('your-class');
```

Comment: Don't I still need the .getElementsByTagName('a'); ? I will try this exactly as you gave it to me. I would much prefer to do this by CSS Class as opposed to multiple DIVs so thank you very much ;-)

Comment: well, you can use .getElementsByTagName('a'); to narrow your search, if you plan to use 'your-class' on other elements than anchors

Comment: Thank you for your help - in the end what worked was: var links = document.querySelectorAll(".article a");

Answer (score 0):

For multiple divs you need to add class name, for example "article":

```
<div class="article"><a>one</a></div>
<div class="article"><a>two</a></div>
```

after this you can get elements by next way:

```
document.querySelectorAll('div.article>a')
```

Comment: Thank you - this works - I ended going with var links = document.querySelectorAll(".article a");